# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que filter no afecte también al texto en CSS3 SASS Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css3, bootstrap-4, sass

tengo un problema de estilo.
Intento darle este efecto a una imagen:
[image: imagen]

El problema es que al agregarle la propiedad `filter`, me cambia el texto de color.

El código `HTML` y `CSS` es el siguiente:

```css
.c-hero {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 10% 70%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)), url(./img/hero.jpg);
  filter: saturate(170%);
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  min-height: 75vh;
}

.text-primary {
  color: theme-color("primary") !important;
}
```

```html
<section class="c-hero">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h1 class="text-primary">Lorem ipsum</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

El color que debería tener el texto, es el siguiente:
`#661E7B` `rbg(102, 30, 123)`

Sin embargo con filter, se cambia por:
`#890FAD` `rgb(137, 15, 173)`

Ya estuve investigando anteriormente en otras páginas y otras preguntas similares, pero ninguna me ha funcionado hasta el momento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes el texto dentro de .c-hero por lo que todo lo que hagas con .c-hero afectara a sus hijos, incluido el texto.
Algunas opciones que tienes:

- Aplicar el filtro al reves al texto, es decir, si le haces un  `filter:saturate(200%);` al padre , aplica un `filter:saturate(50%);` al hijo (el texto, .text-primary ) para "deshacer" el efecto.
- Meter la imagen de forma independiente. Si no quieres/puedes tocar el marcado html puedes hacer algo parecido a :

```css
.c-hero {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  min-height: 75vh;
}
.c-hero:before{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 10% 70%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)), url(./img/hero.jpg);
  filter: saturate(170%);
}
.text-primary {
  color: theme-color("primary") !important;
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, @Montaycabe !